# SQL Server Configuration Manager does not display services

Tags: sql-server, wmi, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an SQL Server 2014 with two database engine, and Windows Server 2012 R2 Service already Started with Local System as pic-1.
[pic-1,Windows Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhMt1.png)
but SQL Server Configuration Manager Only show sqlbrowser as pic-2
[pic-2,SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKmFX.png)
I try to use wbemtest testing wmi,it still only show getsqlbrowser service
And I already use wmimgmt.msc to check root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement12 security setting.

What  can I do with this problem?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Start -> Run -> mmc -> File -> Add/Remove Snap In... -> Add SQL Configuration Manager. From there you should see all services.

Comment: Thank you , I tried it, but it still only show "SQL Server Browser" Service. It seems like WMI to get Namespace:root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement12 didn't find SQL Database Engine. Should I check windows register setting?